# SwiftUI Previews building different schemes/targets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-previews

I am trying to optimize my SwiftUI preview build times.

In my project I have two schemes, one for dev and one for prod, with different configurations. When I kick off a SwiftUI preview build, both schemes are built in sequence. This almost doubles my build time.

Does anyone have an explanation as to why that happens?

**Steps to reproduce:**

I'm working with [XClogparser](https://github.com/MobileNativeFoundation/XCLogParser) to  to visualize my build times.

When I start a regular, non-preview build, only the selected scheme is built, as expected.

When I kick off a SwiftUI preview build, I can see in the build log that after building my dev my production scheme is built as well. The buildscripts and compilations of both schemes are run, in series.

I'm using Xcode 14.1